# How to Update a table field matching with another records of same table

Tags: java, sql

How to Update a table field matching with another records of same table.

```
UPDATE XXXRLES
    SET BIZCAT05 = 'S'
    WHERE ( SELECT A.* FROM XXXRLES A, XXXRLES B
                    WHERE
                        A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
                        AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
                        AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
        );
```

I need to update Field BIZCAT05 by 'S' of table XXXRLES if and only if 2 records having the same values for the  following 3 Fields as:

```
BIZFLD 
BIZOBJ
BIZRUL
```

---

How to make this query?

Comment: Has table `XXXRLES` primary key? and what's the name?

Comment: No Primary key is there.

Comment: If your RDBMS is Oracle then my answer might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed that your RDBMS is Oracle after you've mentioned `ROWID` in comment.

```sql
UPDATE A SET
    BIZCAT05 = 'S'
FROM XXXRLES A
JOIN XXXRLES B ON
    A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
    AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
    AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
    AND A.ROWID <> B.ROWID
```

or using `exists` (which looks clearer, at last for me):

```sql
UPDATE A SET
    BIZCAT05 = 'S'
FROM XXXRLES A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM XXXRLES B
    WHERE A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
    AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
    AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
    AND A.ROWID <> B.ROWID
)
```

**Added** after comment:

I'm not familiar with DB2 but you can try:

```sql
UPDATE XXXRLES A SET
    BIZCAT05 = 'S'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM XXXRLES B
    WHERE A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
    AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
    AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
    AND A.ROWID <> B.ROWID
)
```

Comment: MY RDBMS is DB2. Both query doesn't work due to invalid syntax FROM keyword in Update query...

Comment: Powage, Now Query if fine but DB2 does not support ROWID/ROWNUM fields...hence query is not working

Comment: @Kishore Do you have any field or set of fields that distinguish row from row? That's why I've asked about PK or some kind of ID field.

Comment: @Powage, There is no such type of Field. I think need to create a PK type filed then this will work....Anyways thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can use RID() Row Identifier built-in function to identify unique row. 
The UPDATE query can be written as below:

```
UPDATE XXXRLES A 
SET BIZCAT05 = 'S'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM XXXRLES B
              WHERE A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
                AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
                AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
                AND RID(A) <> RID(B)
              )
```

Please find more information on RID() function in this IBM DB2 Information center. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_rid.htm

Comment: @ Deepa, While running the query get the error: Table designator "A" is not valid for the expression.  SQLSTATE=42703                    Any idea about that

Comment: @Kishore Can you please try with table name instead of A?       UPDATE XXXRLES  
SET BIZCAT05 = 'S'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM XXXRLES B
              WHERE XXXRLES.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD
                AND XXXRLES.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ
                AND XXXRLES.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL
                AND RID(XXXRLES) <> RID(XXXRLES)
              )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, that understood you correctly, try this

```
UPDATE XXXRLES SET BIZCAT05 = 'S' WHERE XXXRLES.ID in
 ( SELECT A.ID FROM XXXRLES A,        XXXRLES B
   WHERE A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL);
```

Comment: Error coming ID is not a Column in table.

Comment: I also tried this query  UPDATE XEXBIZRLES SET BIZCAT05 = 'S' WHERE XEXBIZRLES.ROWID in
 ( SELECT A.ROWID FROM XEXBIZRLES A, XEXBIZRLES B
   WHERE A.BIZFLD = B.BIZFLD AND A.BIZOBJ = B.BIZOBJ AND A.BIZRUL = B.BIZRUL) . But it updated all the records of the table.